# Suitable Question tag for "there comes"

Tags: tag-questions

> There comes the teacher,_________________?

what could be the appropriate question tag for the given sentence?

> doesn't he/she?

or

> doesn't there?

Comment: Doesn't he/she!

Answer (score 1):

> There comes the teacher, doesn't he\she

is the only option that is a properly formed sentence.

`Doesn't there` would sort of imply that *there* was coming.

Answer (score 0):

> There comes the teacher.

There's an inversion in this sentence which often occurs when the sentence starts with an adverbial expression of place. The verb comes before the subject (The teacher comes there). Knowing the subject (the teacher) and the verb (comes),we can easily form the question.

> There comes the teacher, doesn't he/she?